# Performance of activerecord model tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, model, rspec

Being a newbie in TDD and Rails world, I'm trying to figure out how to reduce running time of my specs.

I dropped loading of Rails framework and only load ActiveRecord part. That helped a lot (-8s), though I'm still wondering whether there is more I could do.

The spec file has 5 examples, running it using `time rspec path_to_spec.rb` takes 1.7s. When I removed FactoryGirl and used `Project.create` instead, I got to 1.4s.

What I want to test is whether model's scopes and queries combinations work ok. I'm not sure whether I could use mocking/stubing in this case.

1. Is there a way I could utilize mock/stub features for example to test `next_project`'s behavior?
2. How do I know what is the limit of ActiveRecord interaction timing? I mean, is 1-2s execution time something I have to deal with when testing ActiveRecord models?
3. Any other suggestions on how could I speed up things?

I'm using ruby 1.9.3, rspec 2.1.12, ActiveRecord 3.2.9

My model file:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(:is_enabled => true).order(:position)

  def self.by_slug(slug)
    where(:slug => slug).first
  end
  def find_neighbors
    Neighbors.new(previous_project, next_project)
  end

private
  def previous_project
    Project.where("position < ?", position).last
  end
  def next_project
    Project.where("position > ?", position).first
  end
end

Neighbors = Struct.new(:previous, :next)
```

My spec file:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'yaml'
require 'factory_girl'
require './app/models/project'
dbconfig = YAML::load(File.open('./config/database.yml'))
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(dbconfig["test"])

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project do
    slug { name.parameterize }
    sequence(:position, 1)
    is_enabled true
  end
end

describe Project do
  before(:all) do
    @first_project           = FactoryGirl.create(:project, name: "First Project")
    @second_project_disabled = FactoryGirl.create(:project, name: "Second Project", is_enabled: false)
    @third_project           = FactoryGirl.create(:project, name: "Third Project")
    @fourth_project_disabled = FactoryGirl.create(:project, name: "Fourth Project", is_enabled: false)
    @fifth_project           = FactoryGirl.create(:project, name: "Fifth Project")
  end
  after(:all) do
    projects = [@first_project, @second_project_disabled, @third_project, @fourth_project_disabled, @fifth_project]
    projects.each { |p| p.delete }
  end

  context "when requesting a project by URL slug" do
    it "should return that project if it is enabled" do
      Project.by_slug(@third_project.slug).should eql(Project.find(@third_project.id))
    end
    it "should not return the project if it is not enabled" do
      Project.by_slug(@fourth_project_disabled.slug).should be_nil
    end
  end
  context "when getting first project" do
    it "should have a reference only to the next project enabled" do
      neighbors = @first_project.find_neighbors
      neighbors.previous.should be_nil
      neighbors.next.should eql(Project.find(@third_project.id))
    end
  end

  # 2 more examples similar to the last one
end
```

Comment: I use Zeus to save on the overhead of booting rails.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I was using spork to boot up rails, but found out it doesn't help. So I got rid of it for now. I don't know performance comparison to Zeus though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from tuning your database to try and get it to run faster, as many ship with a severely sub-optimal default configuration, it's just one of those things you'll have to deal with. There's a few things that can help, though.

Ruby 1.9.3 is a lot faster at initializing the Rails environment than previous versions, so it's good you're using that. It used to take ~20s on some machines simply to bring up a console. That's improved lately due to some internal optimizations.

Still, don't expect your unit tests to run instantaneously. A couple of seconds is usually not a big deal. When you can, run *focused* tests, that is one test method at a time, then the whole test module, then the whole test suite. There are a number of plug-ins for popular editors that can help with this.

The good news is there's some work being done for Rails 4 to make a [more persistent testing process](https://twitter.com/dhh/status/281878921602031617) but it's not clear if this will be in the released version.

Comment: +1 for focused tests. Though it doesn't make a difference for my case. I found out that just the fact I'm requiring ActiveRecord, connecting to database (hash or YAML don't make a difference) and requiring a model file - these all tasks take up to 1.1s. Which is approximately the penalty I got.